# How to add tag to a Kinesis Firehose Delivery stream through cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am creating Kinesis firehose via cloudformation template. Need to add tags to it. How to add tag to a Kinesis Firehose Delivery stream through cloudformation template?

Answer (score 0):

This option is not available yet.
Per the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/firehose-tagging.html:

Tagging Delivery Streams Using the Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose API
You can specify tags when you invoke CreateDeliveryStream to create a new delivery stream. For existing delivery streams, you can add, list, and remove tags using the following three operations:

- TagDeliveryStream
- ListTagsForDeliveryStream
- UntagDeliveryStream

Currently, you can add tags using API:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_TagDeliveryStream.html

Or CLI:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/firehose/tag-delivery-stream.html

Answer (score 0):

This works for me when I deploy with SAM

```
YourDeliveryStream:
    Type: AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream
    DependsOn:
      - YOUR_DELIVERY_STREAM_POLICY
    Properties:
      DeliveryStreamName: YOUR_DS_NAME
      DeliveryStreamType: DirectPut
      Tags:
        - Key: "owner"
          Value: my_name
        - Key: "purpose"
          Value: to_stream_data
```